# Keyboard not hiding after push done or leave Entry

Tags: maui

I am facing a problem with hiding the `Keyboard` after I am done using it or `leave` the `Entry` and touching the screen somewhere.

In Xamarin Forms, it is working normally, the Keyboard is hiding but in `Maui` it is not?

```
<CheckBox
            x:Name="Cbbb1"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0"/>

        <Entry
            x:Name="Ebb1"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Keyboard="Numeric" />
```

Remove `Keyboard="Numeric"` is not helping.

I am using **VisualStudio 2022 preview Version 17.1.0 Preview 3.0**.

I also tried this:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KeyboardhideMaui"
```

And this:

```
     <Entry.Triggers>
 <DataTrigger TargetType="Entry" >
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <local:FocusTriggerAction Focused="True" />
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <local:FocusTriggerAction Focused="False" />
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
</Entry.Triggers>
 
            <CheckBox
                x:Name="Cbbb1"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="0" />

            <Entry
                x:Name="Ebb1"
                Grid.Row="2"
                Grid.Column="2"
                Keyboard="Numeric" />
```

Class

```
 public class FocusTriggerAction : TriggerAction<Entry>
{
    public bool Focused { get; set; }
    protected override async void Invoke(Entry entry)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        if (Focused)
        {
            entry.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
          entry.UnFocus();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting below error on  `entry.UnFocus();`:

> 'Entry' does not contain a definition for 'UnFocus' and no accessible extension method
> 'UnFocus' accepting a first argument of type 'Entry' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I don't see any bug open for it. If there is a difference in how it behaves on Forms and .NET MAUI it might be worth opening a detailed issue.

Comment: try Editor control

Answer (score 1):

try this please :

Add this in your xaml page ( page resources )

```
        <Style TargetType="Entry">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger Event="Unfocused">
                    <local:UnFocusTriggerAction />
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

then add UnFocusTriggerAction in your project

```
 public class UnFocusTriggerAction : TriggerAction<Entry>
    {
        protected override void Invoke(Entry entry)
        {
           entry.Unfocus();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact issue. Here is how I solved it:

```
Entry entry = new Entry { };
    
void OnEntryCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string text = ((Entry)sender).Text;            
    entry.IsEnabled = false;
    entry.IsEnabled = true;
}

entry.Completed += OnEntryCompleted;
```

Specifically, the .IsEnabled being set to false, when the Done button is pressed (entry.Completed), is what dismisses the virtual keyboard. This completely disables the entry field but retains the value that had been entered. I make sure to set .IsEnabled back to true so that the user can edit that field again.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `HideSoftInputOnTapped` property for your `ContentPage`. This setting ensures that tapping anywhere on the page will trigger the hiding of the soft input.

```xml
<ContentPage
   x:Class="SampleApp.Views.HomePage"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   HideSoftInputOnTapped="True">
   <ContentPage.Resources>
      <!-- Your Content -->
   </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```